# Regarding writing custom html helper for hidden field with few good feature ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

this way i can write custom helper for hidden field

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace CustomHtmlHelpers.CustomHelpers
{
    public static class CustomHiddenHelperModelBinding
    {
        //This overload accepts single expression as parameter.
        public static MvcHtmlString Custom_HiddenFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {
            return Custom_HiddenFor(helper, expression, null);
        }

        //This overload accepts expression and htmlAttributes object as parameter.
        public static MvcHtmlString Custom_HiddenFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            //Fetching the metadata related to expression. This includes name of the property, model value of the property as well.
            ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
            string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
            //Fetching the property name.
            string propertyName = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();

            //Creating a textarea tag using TagBuilder class.
            TagBuilder hidden = new TagBuilder("input");

            //Setting the type attribute to hidden to render hidden input field.
            hidden.Attributes.Add("type", "hidden");

            //Setting the name and id attribute.
            hidden.Attributes.Add("name", propertyName);
            hidden.Attributes.Add("id", propertyName);

            //Setting the value attribute of textbox with model value if present.
            if (metadata.Model != null)
            {
                hidden.Attributes.Add("value", metadata.Model.ToString());
            }
            //merging any htmlAttributes passed.
            hidden.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(hidden.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }
    }
}
```

later we can access it like

```
@Html.Custom_HiddenFor(Model => Model.hidden)
@Html.Custom_HiddenFor(Model => Model.hidden, new { @class = "hiddenClass" })
```

my objective to rewrite my own html helper for hidden field is to render value at client side as encrypted text and as well as tamper proof.
if anyone tamper data then i want to check at server side and if tamper then i will show friendly error message to user.

this is another sampe code for encryption with machine key but i am not sure the that code works fine in partial trust environment or not?

### here is the sample code

```
string Protect(byte[] data)
{
    if (data == null || data.Length == 0) return null;
    return MachineKey.Encode(data, MachineKeyProtection.All);
}

byte[] Unprotect(string value)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) return null;
    return MachineKey.Decode(value, MachineKeyProtection.All);
}


 here’s the 4.5 usage (it supports a slightly more sophisticated usage)
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 const string MachineKeyPurpose = "MyApp:Username:{0}";
 const string Anonymous = "<anonymous>";

 string GetMachineKeyPurpose(IPrincipal user)
 {
     return String.Format(MachineKeyPurpose,
         user.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? user.Identity.Name : Anonymous);
 }

 string Protect(byte[] data)
 {
     if (data == null || data.Length == 0) return null;
     var purpose = GetMachineKeyPurpose(Thread.CurrentPrincipal);
     var value = MachineKey.Protect(data, purpose);
     return Convert.ToBase64String(value);
 }

 byte[] Unprotect(string value)
 {
     if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) return null;
     var purpose = GetMachineKeyPurpose(Thread.CurrentPrincipal);
     var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
     return MachineKey.Unprotect(bytes, purpose);
}
```

### another way to encrypt

```
To generate a random string, use the RNGCryptoServiceProvider.

public string GenerateSalt(int length)
{
    var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    var buffer = new byte[length];
    rng.GetBytes(buffer);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
}
```

Now we can generate a hashed password using the function below

```
public virtual string CreatePasswordHash(string password, string saltkey, string passwordFormat = "SHA1")
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordFormat))
        passwordFormat = "SHA1";
    string saltAndPassword = String.Concat(password, saltkey);
    string hashedPassword =
        FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(
            saltAndPassword, passwordFormat);
    return hashedPassword;
}
```

so guide me how can i rewrite my own custom html helper which will encrypt data in most secure way and later which can be check to make sure the
value is tamper or not at client side.

i have another requirement to easily decrypt the value when form will post and action method will be called.
i want to decrypt the encrypted value using a attribute on action method. i want to fire a function will fire before action method and decrypt 
value before data de-serialize to model or to action method argument.

is it possible ?

### i want that my action method would look like

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Decrypt]
 public ActionResult Save(string personname, string email)
 {
       return View();
 }

 or

 [HttpPost]
 [Decrypt]
 public ActionResult Save(Person oPerson)
 {
        return View();
 }
```

i want that my [Decrypt] attribute will fire a method call decypt and pass all value to decypt() function just before action method Save would invoke.
 if decypt() function found any encrypted value then it will decrypt and de-serialize decypted value to model or to action method argument.

so i have three requirements

---

1) i want to write a custom html helper which will render hidden field with encrypted value.

2) when data post to server there i can detect that value has been tamper or not. 
 if tamper then a error page with proper message will be shown to user.

3)
 action method will have custom attribute which will invoke a function before action method execution. 
 that function will decrypt value if any encrypted value found. after decryption the decrypted value will be properly De-serialize to model
 or other action method argument properly.

i am new in MVC. so guide me how should i move forward with sample code. thanks

Answer (score 2):

What about `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`?

"Generates a hidden form field (anti-forgery token) that is validated when the form is submitted." [Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470175%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Example:
1. In your markup add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to the form.
2. Add `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute your controller action.

[Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: i am not aware of @Html.AntiForgeryToken(). so i like to know that [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute check that hidden filed value has been tamper or manipulated at client side or not?

Comment: i would definitely try to dig for @Html.AntiForgeryToken() searching google but if u know about good article on it then please make me aware. thanks

Comment: is it at all possible to decrypt value writing custom action filter. if possible then redirect us to right article.

Comment: Well, google is our best friend :)
Here are some links:
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/when-the-use-of-a-antiforgerytoken-is-not-required-needed
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-(csrf)-attacks
http://www.devcurry.com/2013/01/what-is-antiforgerytoken-and-why-do-i.html#.UkFhxYakpCg

I am sure there are many better ones you can find.

Comment: @Mou: Why do you want to decrypt the value?
(I have antiforgerytoken on each form. MVC takes care of it and I dont need to do anything about it.)

Comment: here i asked that i want to emit hidden fields with encrypted value and i want to decrypt the value when form will post and before executing action method.the decryption part i want to do it with custom model binding. but u said to use AntiForgeryToken().